# Convert Xpath to selector for jsoup

Tags: xpath, jsoup, selector

I have a xpath query that I need to convert to selector for Jsoup but have difficult to understand how to solve it.

I have looked at this page but still not understood.

Xpath-query:

```
//*[text()='SomeText']//parent::div//following-sibling::div//following::div[contains(@class,'SomeMarket')]
```

I tried the following but are probably far away from my goal..

```
doc.select("#SomeText").parents().select("div").first().siblingElements().select("div:contains('SomeMarket')");
```

The idea throws the following error:

> Cannot invoke "org.jsoup.nodes.Element.siblingElements()" because the return value of "org.jsoup.select.Elements.first()" is null so I guess it is wrong already at .parents()

The XPath query when I test it in the Chrome developer tool.
Can someone please give some hints or tips please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end with something like this:

> doc.select("div[class='someclass']:contains(SomeText)").get(0).parent().nextElementSibling().select("div[class='someclass2'] > div > div");